# Cannot takeownership or delete Flash files

Tags: permissions, flash

I cannot take ownership nor change the permissions for some of the Flash files, away from “TrustedInstaller,” nor can I remove “TrustedInstaller” from the permissions in the first place, yes, I am on an administrator account:

[image]

Comment: Use the uninstaller to remove Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what version of Windows you're running on, but from the screenshot, it's something newer than Win7. Win8 and later have a bundled version of Flash that is considered an OS file and gets updates through Windows Update. This bundled file, like others that come with the OS, is generally under very tight security to prevent people from tampering with it. Still, an Administrator *should* be able to do so. You can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker for more info.

Admins should always be able to take ownership of any file - they have the **SeTakeOwnership** privilege, which allows them to bypass ACLs for that operation - so I'm not sure what's up there. Do you get an actual error message when you try? You could try it from the command line: open CMD or Powershell as Administrator, go to the relevant directory, and try running `takeown /f FlashUtil_ActiveX.exe`. If that actually fails (with an error), something weird is going on. If the owner just doesn't seem to change, the system may be reverting the file's owner immediately.

To delete the file, even an Admin would need to close all handles to the file first; make sure nothing is using Flash. The obvious culprit would be an `iexplore` process - possibly even an invisible or hung one - but Flash ActiveX can be loaded in anything that supports ActiveX, which is a long list. Consider using Resource Monitor (`resmon.exe`) to check all open HANDLEs (look under the CPU tab) for a process that has `Flash*` open (or, since this is an executable itself, check for any running instances of that process). Close the HANDLEs and/or kill the processes, then try again. Note that, as

If that still doesn't work... kind of suspicious. You can try booting into another OS, such as a Linux Live CD, and then mounting your Windows volume and nuking the file that way. That *really* shouldn't be required, though.